# CTRL+ALT+DOWN/UP does not duplicates line in Spring Tool Suite, how to fix it?

Tags: eclipse, spring-tool-suite

Spring Tool Suite though based on Eclipse, does not duplicates line using the usual `CTRL+ALT+DOWN/UP` key combination. I can still see in the key binding that this key combination says `Duplicates the selected lines and moves the selection to the copy` When says `Editing Text`, tried changing it to Editing Java, HTML, etc, but that all did not help.

How do get the key combination back, can I import it from existing Eclipse IDE as is ?

Thanks.

Comment: The CTRL-ALT-UP/DOWN keys don't work for me either. This seems to be because they are already taken by Ubuntu's window manager to switch workspaces. I reassigned the keybinding to be CTRL-ALT-SHIFT-UP/DOWN then it seems to work fine. What OS are you on? Maybe try to rebind the 'Duplicate Lines' shortcut to something else and see if that works. I also tried 'unbinding' CTRL-ALT-UP/DOWN keys from Unity but didn't have much success with that (see http://askubuntu.com/questions/315625/how-to-disable-the-shortcut-ctrl-alt-arrow-in-gnome-3-8)

Comment: After figuring out how to disable CTRL-ALT-arrow keybindings in Ubuntu, copy-lines-up-down is working now for me in STS 3.6.3 with its standard keybinding.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 20.04. Neither CTRL-ALT-UP/DOWN nor CTRL-ALT-SHIFT-UP/DOWN shortcut key works in my system. I don't want to disable the Ubuntu/gnome default shortcut key. Are there any alternative methods for this?

Answer (score 4):

Run this commands to disable the shurtcuts from gnome that is disabling the shurtcuts from eclipse

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-down "['']"

$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-up "['']"
```